# Collapse any runs of lines longer than n into one, maintaining integrity of any other instances of the line

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a file of domain names formatted like this:

```
www.mozilla.org
www.mozilla.org
www.mozilla.org
www.mozilla.org
www.google.com
www.google.com
www.rust-lang.org
www.google.com
www.google.com
www.google.com
www.google.com
```

I would like to collapse any runs of the same line IFF the run is longer than, for example, 4. This would give me output data of:

```
www.mozilla.org
www.google.com
www.google.com
www.rust-lang.org
www.google.com
```

I'm looking to do this in Bash, and the closest I've gotten is this 5-minute naive solution in Python:

```py
inp = """www.mozilla.org
www.mozilla.org
www.mozilla.org
www.mozilla.org
www.google.com
www.google.com
www.rust-lang.org
www.google.com
www.google.com
www.google.com
www.google.com"""

def collapse(n, inp):
    prev = ""
    output = []
    cnt = 0
    for line in inp.split('\n'):
        if line == prev:
            cnt += 1
        if line != prev:
            if cnt >= n-1:
                output = output[:-cnt]
            cnt = 0
        prev = line
        output.append(line)
    #last set of lines is an edgecase
    if cnt > n-2:
        output = output[:-cnt]

    print('\n'.join(output))
            

collapse(4, inp)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `uniq -c` to count the length of the runs and then `awk` to output the data an appropriate number of times, based on those counts:

```bash
$ uniq -c file | awk '$1 >= 4 { $1 = 1 } { for (i = 1; i <= $1; ++i) print $2 }'
www.mozilla.org
www.google.com
www.google.com
www.rust-lang.org
www.google.com
```

The `uniq -c` command would, with the example data, output the following lines:

```
   4 www.mozilla.org
   2 www.google.com
   1 www.rust-lang.org
   4 www.google.com
```

The `awk` command acts on the numbers in the first column and outputs the second column's value that number of times if the number is less than 4; otherwise, it outputs it a single time.

Comment: `uniq -c` would be more globally available then `datamash`

Comment: @glennjackman So it is. I've been using `datamash` so much recently that I forgot the more common tools. I will update. Thanks a bunch for poking me.